# Color formatting when searching excel

Tags: excel, vba, background-color, paste

I currently have a macro that will search an excel spreadsheet and then place the results in a different sheet.  The only issue is is that it wont copy the color formatting when transferring the results. Here is the code.  I have tried paste special but it doesnt work for all the results.

```
Sub Searchcustomer()    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Search")

    If ws.Range("B3").Value = "" And ws.Range("B4").Value = "" And ws.Range("B5").Value = "" And ws.Range("B6").Value = "" And ws.Range("B7").Value = "" And ws.Range("B8").Value = "" Then
                MsgBox "Please Enter Data into Table"
                Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim msheet As Worksheet
    Dim ssheet As Worksheet
    Dim stand  As String
    Dim number As String
    Dim customer As String
    Dim states As String
    Dim find As String
    Dim audit As String
    Dim saudit As String
    Dim est As String
    Dim pub As String
    Dim finalrow As Integer
    Dim finalrow2 As Integer
    Dim i As Integer

    Set msheet = Sheet4
    Set ssheet = Sheet5

    number = ssheet.Range("B3").Value
    customer = ssheet.Range("B4").Value
    states = ssheet.Range("B5").Value
    find = ssheet.Range("B6").Value
    audit = ssheet.Range("B7").Value
    saudit = ssheet.Range("B8").Value

    msheet.Select
    finalrow = msheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 1 To finalrow
        If IIf(stand <> "", msheet.Cells(i, 1) = number, True) And IIf(number <> "", msheet.Cells(i, 2) = number, True) And IIf(customer <> "", msheet.Cells(i, 3) = customer, True) And IIf(states <> "", Cells(i, 4) = states, True) And IIf(find <> "", Cells(i, 5) = find, True) And IIf(audit <> "", Cells(i, 6) = audit, True) And IIf(saudit <> "", Cells(i, 7) = saudit, True) And IIf(est <> "", msheet.Cells(i, 8) = number, True) And IIf(pub <> "", msheet.Cells(i, 9) = number, True) Then
            msheet.Range(msheet.Cells(i, 1), msheet.Cells(i, 9)).Copy
            ssheet.Range("A100").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(1, 9).Value = msheet.Range(msheet.Cells(i, 1), msheet.Cells(i, 9)).Value

        End If
    Next i

    ssheet.Select
    ssheet.Range("B3").Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you if you use

```
ssheet.Range("A100").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(1, 9).Value = msheet.Range(msheet.Cells(i, 1), msheet.Cells(i, 9)).Value
```

it olny transfers the value but no formattings.

And if you use `.Copy` you need to specify the destination. You didn't and therefore your `.Copy` line does nothing at all.   * *See Mathieu's comment below.*

Throw out the `.Value` line and replace the `.Copy` line with the following:

```
msheet.Range(msheet.Cells(i, 1), msheet.Cells(i, 9)).Copy Destination:=ssheet.Range("A100").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(1, 9)
```

---

Note that row counting variables must be of type `Long` Excel has more rows than `Integer` can handle!

```
Dim finalrow As Long
Dim finalrow2 As Long
Dim i As Long
```

Comment: "You didn't and therefore your .Copy line does nothing at all" - not exactly true: it did copy the contents to the clipboard, making the content available for a subsequent `Paste` or `PasteSpecial` call, and toggling global-state `Application.CutCopyMode` to `True`. But yeah, it didn't copy the contents where the OP meant to paste it.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the fedback and it does work for posting the formatting, however now i have the same values duplicated.  It will post one with formatting and one without.  Any tips on how to fix that?

Comment: Hello, works great! When I tried it the first time it didnt work, however I saved it and now it works great!  The only thing I did differently was change back the integers because my excel kept freezing.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Yes, of course, I should have been more clear about that ;)

Comment: @Tara `Long` vs `Integer` isn't going to make a difference with Excel "freezing". However `Integer` row numbers will absolutely crash with run-time error 6 "Overflow" as soon as you try to assign them a value greater than 32,767. There is no reason whatsoever to ever have an `Integer` in VBA, unless you're invoking Win32 API functions that *require* working with a 16-bit integer and blow up if you give them a 32-bit one (that's `Long`).

Comment: What *does* make Excel go "(not responding)" though, is repeatedly accessing a worksheet inside a loop body: the UI thread (the only thread available to VBA) is busy running your loop, and thus isn't updating Excel. Excel isn't "frozen", it's just busy running your loop.